# Imagej : How to save work in an editable way.With ROI measure and image associated togheter?

Tags: roi, imagej

In ImageJ i need to save all the ROI Measure (in the ROI manager) associated with the image.
And have the possibility to open lately still editable (move the Line , move the point , save measure in result)
So also have ImageJ a File where can save a work we are doing and open lately for re-editing?

Answer (score 3):

You can save the ROI Manager's set of ROIs by clicking the More button and choosing "Save" from the menu. To restore them later, click "More" and choose "Open" from the menu.

[image: The ROI Manager's More menu]